# Convert yyyymmdd number or string to true Date value in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a query that has a date field in this format (yyyymmdd) just numbers. I am reformatting the the field by creating a calculated field using the following formula:

```
[DateField] = Date(Left( [DateField] ,4),Mid( [DateField] ,5,2),Right( [DateField] ,2))
```

I keep getting a message saying my formula contains wrong number of arguments!! 
This formula always worked in Excel.

Please advise

Cheers

Comment: In Access, `Date()` is a function which accepts no arguments.  Beyond that I don't understand what you want to accomplish.  When your `DateField` contains the text, *"20150821"*, what do you want to replace it with?  It looks like your expression would give you  *"20150821"* back again.

Comment: I think you want the [DateSerial()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DateSerial-Function-a0128476-83a0-407c-831a-93f2b046f503) function.

Comment: @GordThompson Thank you. It worked :)

@ HansUP the field is designated for date but it comes out as numbers. So I wanted to properly format it before exporting the data to Excel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Access you'll need to use the [DateSerial()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DateSerial-Function-a0128476-83a0-407c-831a-93f2b046f503) function:

```vbs
DateSerial(Left([DateField], 4), Mid([DateField], 5, 2), Right([DateField], 2))
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using CDate function and type in the appropriate format for date

```
NewDate: CDate(Format([TextField], "0000-00-00"))
```

Comment: could you provide a bit of detail to make this answer better at helping future readers? and format the code by highlighting it and hitting Ctrl+K

Comment: Just used this - worked perfectly and is simpler than the one above so +1 (and I also modified the format as suggested)

Comment: This code worked like charm. Thank you for sharing this insight. Some explanation to the code on how this works would add clarity.